# ¿Cómo extraer un valor de tipo entero de MYSQL para hacerle una resta desde NetBeans?

Tags: java, mysql

Quiero extraer el valor entero de un registro para poder hacerle una resta desde NetBeans pero no me deja extraerlo y no se por que, este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
  private void vender(){
      Connection con = null;
      PreparedStatement ps;
      char cad[];
      String codigo="";
      cad=producto.getSelectedItem().toString().toCharArray();
      for(int i=0;i<cad.length;i++){
          if(cad[i]!='-'){
              codigo=codigo+cad[i];
          }else{
          break;
          }
      }
      if(producto.getSelectedItem().equals("Seleccione el producto... ")){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Seleccione un producto");
      }else{
            try{
            con=Conection.getConection();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT stock FROM producto WHERE codigo='"+codigo+"';");
            int valor = rs.getInt("stock");
            valor=valor-1;
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Qué quieres decir con _"no me deja extraerlo"_, ¿hay algún error? o ¿qué es lo que ocurre?

Comment: Después de restarle uno quiero imprimir el valor y no me aparece nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el demás código funciona y el error solo es en la consulta, hace falta mover el cursor una fila dentro del ResultSet. Esto se requiere porque inicialmente el cursor se sitúa antes de la primera fila, entonces colocando rs.next() accedemos al primer registro devuelto. Por lo tanto, tu código tal y como esta, debería funcionar de la siguiente manera:

```
//... código

try{
   con=Conection.getConection();
   Statement st = con.createStatement();
   rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT stock FROM producto WHERE codigo='"+codigo+"';");
   if(rs.next()){
       int valor = rs.getInt("stock");
       valor=valor-1;
   }
}catch(Exception e){
   //Maneja aquí tus excepciones SQL
}

//... código
```

Ahora, propongo utilizar PreparedStatement en tus consultas para evitar inyección de código SQL, aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
//... código

try{
    con=Conection.getConection();
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT stock FROM producto WHERE codigo = ?");  
    ps.setString(1, codigo);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeUpdate;
    if(rs.next()){
        int valor = rs.getInt("stock");
        valor=valor-1;
    }
catch(Exception e){
    //Maneja aquí tus excepciones SQL
}

//... código
```